# update a payara jndi variable using asadmin

Tags: payara, asadmin

I want to update a jndi variable `testVar` on my payara server that is a string type via the command line.

I see this online site https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1751/giwlk/index.html showing the following example of how to update but it looks confusing:

```
asadmin> set server.resources.custom-resource.custom
/my-custom-resource.property.value=2010server.resources.custom-resource.custom
/my-custom-resource.property.value=2010
```

It looks like a mix/mash of 3 different commands.  I've tried some variations and keep getting this error:

`remote failure: invalid name value pair server.resources.custom.custom-resource.myresource. Missing expected equal sign`

Answer (score 1):

Finally figured it out.  The command to update a jndi variable is:

`asadmin> set server.resources.custom-resource.testVar.property.value=HelloWorld`

I then get a `Command set executed successfully` on the command line.

Note you can change the `testVar` above with whatever jndi variable name you have and update its property.value to the value you want.

Now when I go to the payara web console I can see that updated value.